# KnockoutJS Mapping ko.computed Array into observableArray

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

As the question states, I am trying to make an array result from a ko.computed into observable array. The reason I am doing this is that I'd like to make all objects inside my array result to be "observable" and the solution Im trying to work out is by transferring the array result into a different observableArray. I can't explain clearly so here is my code (see the commented lines for further explanation):

```
//to make each objects observable
var DropDownHolder = function (itemID, itemName, amount, automatic) {
    var self = this;
    self.ID = ko.observable(deductionID);
    self.Name = ko.observable(deductionName);
    self.amount = ko.observable(amount);
    self.automatic = ko.observable(automatic);
};

//temporary list, creates a new filtered array -- no problem here
self.temporaryDropDown = ko.computed(function () {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.completeList(), function (completeItem) {
        var sameItem = false;

        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.selectedItem(), function (pickedItem) {
            if (pickedItem.itemID() == completeItem.itemID()) {
                sameItem = true;
                return;
            }
        });
        return !sameItem;
    });
}, self);

//put unpicked in dropdown -- problem here
//cannot transfer contents of temporaryDropDown to DropDown
self.DropDown = ko.observableArray();
self.DropDown(ko.utils.arrayMap(self.temporaryDropDown(), function (dd) {
    return new DropDownHolder(dd.itemID, dd.itemName, dd.amount, dd.automatic);
}));
```

Comment: @supercool that's the problem man, console doesn't throw any errors..

Comment: @supercool yes that's what I was saying browser console doesn't throw any error.

Comment: @supercool something's wrong here, it cant populate self.Dropdown for unknown reason `self.DropDown = ko.observableArray();
self.DropDown(ko.utils.arrayMap(self.temporaryDropDown(), function (dd) {
    return new DropDownHolder(dd.itemID, dd.itemName, dd.amount, dd.automatic);
}));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code just looks fine which should definitely work

> I believe `temporaryDropDown` is computed something making it to fire
>   twice  i.e initial load you get [] later you get actual data .

Find what making computed to fire more than once that should do it .